# Change SQL credential before build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have to deploy jar to 2 different environments DEV and QA but before this need
to change SQL parameters in a .jar by passing them as a  parameter to job defined and then promote them to particular environments?
Please advise as I am new to JENKINS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your pipeline code. Are you using Jenkins Pipeline or Job DSL?

Comment: I have just build my code nothing else  have to start promotion process
Don't know the best process to do the same.Please suggest that too.Thanks

Comment: That's then very broad...where should we start explaining?